How are the reactants of cellular respiration distributed to form the products?
This may be a very basic question, but I am essentially wondering if the cellular respiration equation that is usually given (C6H12O6+6O2=6CO2+6H2O) is the real equation; that is, is it simplified in any way? I know that the equation for photosynthesis was simplified for teaching purposes, so I was wondering if the same was done for the cellular respiration equation.
The reason I am confused about this is because I am unclear which reactants help form which products. In the equation for photosynthesis, only the water molecules are used to form the oxygen byproduct. This means 6H2O=6O2, which is obviously incorrect because there are 6 oxygen molecules in the reactant and 12 in the product. I looked it up and there is an additional 6H2O on each side of the equation for photosynthesis, which was subtracted from both sides to simplify it for teaching purposes. Basically, I am wondering which reactants of cellular respiration form which products, and whether anything that doesn't add up indicates that the equation was simplified.
If this question is too simple or basic, could anyone comment a trustworthy site that provides this information? I haven't been able to find one. Thanks!

Yes, simplified a great deal. First off, the equation does not seem to include the net gain of ATP (the "high energy" molecule) that cellular respiration provides, which is the whole reason behind doing the process in the first place. Secondly, cellular respiration has 4 major steps: glycolysis, the link reaction, the TCA (or Krebs) cycle, and oxidative phosphorylation. Oxidative phosphorylation is the real energy maker, producing a lot of ATP using the products obtained from the previous 3 reactions. Mechanistic details are readily available through a Google search.

It is the summary equation of the complex reaction mechanism, with its particular steps ongoing in different places and different times.

As already indicated by Sonder and Poutnik, the reaction
$$\ce{C6H12O6 + 6O2 = 6CO2 + 6H2O}$$
is the net reaction of respiration and a very simple representation of a complex set of metabolic processes. There is no reason to go through them all here, but I think your question of where the products emerge, is an interesting one.
Glucose is broken into smaller pieces first in a series of 10 reactions known as glycolysis, from which the main product is pyruvate. The products in the net reaction, $\ce{CO2}$ or $\ce{H2O}$, are not formed during glycolysis.
Next, the pyruvate enters the tricarboxylic acid (TCA) cycle, a.k.a. the citric acid cycle, which is a series of reactions that take place inside the mitochondrion. From the reactions in the TCA cycle, all 6 $\ce{CO2}$ molecules are formed, but in different steps. Four $\ce{H2O}$ per initial glucose molecule are also consumed in the TCA cycle, so we have a "yield" of -4 $\ce{H2O}$ there.
Finally, an important point of the TCA cycle is to produce the reductant NADH. (NADH is also formed in one of the steps of glycolysis). NADH will carry electrons to the mitochondrial electron transport chain, or respiratory chain, where most of the oxygen is consumed and the water is produced.
The result of breaking down one glucose molecule, is generating 10 reducing electron carriers, which leads to the consumption of 5 $\ce{O2}$ molecules and the formation of 10 $\ce{H2O}$ molecules in the final step of the respiratory chain. As 4 $\ce{H2O}$ molecules were consumed by the TCA cycle per glucose molecule, we arrive at the net production of 6 $\ce{H2O}$ molecules, as per the net reaction.
The last $\ce{O2}$ molecule missing from the equation is actually added right at the beginning of the TCA cycle, "hidden" in one of the reactants (acetyl-CoA).
All of this complicated stuff is done just to generate enough ATP for driving cellular metabolism. But that is a different question.
